# Why aren't CSS files served? There is nothing in sites/default/files/css

Tags: 8, theming

In my Drupal 8 installation profile, I install a theme and a lot of configuration for it.  I'm using Features to install blocks/settings/views for it, but when I enable the feature Drupal stops serving ANY CSS files on page loads.

I don't think it's an issue with features, because if I wait long enough, those files will be generated by Drupal and CSS files will load as normal, it's just that Drupal assumes those files already exist.

I have tried:
- drush cr
- clearing the cache manually in the UI
- all of the individual drush cc options
- deleting the contents of all cache_* tables and clearing the cache or drush cr
- turning aggregated css off, clearing caches, turning it back on, clearing caches
- running cron
- running /update.php

...Is there any way I can tell Drupal to generate these files instead of waiting hours for it?

Comment: If CC is not working right away then the issue is not with Drupal or its caching. I think it might be an issue with features and configuration. Maybe features store some data in configuration instead of cache and that causes this behavior, which means Features have a bug..which is not surprising since they are not stable yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few more things to check when you have issues like this:

- **Any noteworthy issues on the Status page?** *(admin/reports/status)*
- **Does saving the File system page generate any errors?** *(admin/config/media/file-system)* 
  This sometimes indicates permission or ownership issues in the file structure, which could keep the aggregate CSS and JS files from being generated?
- **Have you checked the error log for any noteworthy messages?** *(admin/reports/dblog)*

Clearing the cache is a good place to start, but I see that you already did that. Try checking the error log immediately after clearing the cache to see if anything pops up.